# how to get count of a column along with column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

is there any other way for this problem .I wanted to use group by cant use ii.
my solution:

```
SQL> select (select count(dr_id) 
     from cus_detail c 
     where c.dr_id=d.dr_id) as count_cus,dr_name from driver_detail d;

 COUNT_CUS DR_NAME
---------- ---------------
     1 raju
     0 mandi
     2 sajuman
     3 babu ram coi
     0 daju
     0 bare babu
```

Comment: what is the error exactly you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

use this one.

```
select count(c.dr_id) as count_cus, d.dr_name 
    from driver_detail d
    inner join cus_detail c on c.dr_id=d.dr_id
    group by d.dr_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure I understand what you're asking but I think you're asking how to group things and bring in data from another table

I typically prefer to do this as a grouping subquery:

```
select 
  d.dr_name,
  c.ctr
from 
 (select dr_id, count(dr_id) ctr from cus_detail group by dr_id) c
INNER JOIN driver_detail d ON c.dr_id=d.dr_id
```

The reason why here is that by grouping on the `id` when counting means we can keep a count for two different people (i.e. different `id`) both called John. If instead we joined on `id` then grouped on the `Name` then two different people  both called John would have their counts added together

It's also good to group and count in a subquery because sometimes grouping and counting in the outer query introduces wrong counts if three or more tables are related in 1:Many fashion. If a record in a had 3 records in b and 4 records in c, and we join all before we count we will count 12 records. If we group first we will be joining in 1:1 relationship instead and the counter won't inflate erroneously

Answer (score 0):

If two DR_NAME are same then GROUP BY can give different result then what your current query will give.

So better to use an analytical function as the following:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(C.DR_ID) OVER(
        PARTITION BY C.DR_ID
    ) AS COUNT_CUS,
    DR_NAME
FROM
    DRIVER_DETAIL D
    JOIN CUS_DETAIL C ON ( C.DR_ID = D.DR_ID )
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a basic aggregation query.  Your method is correct (although it could be formatted better).  The more standard method is `join`/`group by`:

```
select d.dr_name, count(c.dr_id) 
from driver_detail d left join
     cus_detail c 
     on c.dr_id = d.dr_id 
group by d.dr_name;
```